# How do I create a new page in a MediaWiki via the API?

Tags: mediawiki-api

I'd like to create a new page in a MediaWiki via the API. According to the documentation this should be accomplished by setting the `action` to `edit` and then specifying a set of parameters, e.g. like this:

- `bot = false`
- `contentformat = "text/x-wiki"`
- `contentmodel = "wikitext"`
- `createonly = false`
- `minor = true`
- `nocreate = false`
- `recreate = true`
- `summary = ""`
- `text = "........"`
- `title = "SomeTitle123"`

And of course the CSRF-token.

However if I try to create a page using these parmeters I get the following error response:

- `code: "missingtitle"`
- `info: "The page you specified doesn't exist."`

It seems that in contrast to the API documentation the API rejects my attempt to create a page. What am I missing here? How is it possible to create a new page in MediaWiki using the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the data specified in the question is already the correct data to send to the API for creating a new wiki page.

Unfortunately a simple but very important detail has to be considered: The MediaWiki API recognizes **boolean variables not by their value but by their presence**. That means: If you specify `nocreate = false` literally in your data structure that means `nocreate = true` for the API.

The correct way to specify data for the MediaWiki API is to leave out any boolean variable that contains `false`.

Therefore the correct data to send to the API is the following:

- `contentformat = "text/x-wiki"`
- `contentmodel = "wikitext"`
- `minor = true`
- `recreate = true`
- `summary = ""`
- `text = "........"`
- `title = "SomeTitle123"`